# Can we retrieve query selector from node element?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to retrieve a node element query selector ?

From a node list :

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll(".card .text-data, .section-1")
```

I need to loop over each element in `targets` and find again `.card .text-data` and `.section-1` in a parsed HTML to get data so I can compare both version.

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(htmlData, 'text/html');

targets.forEach(function (targetElement) {
    let new_data = parsedHtml.querySelector("my selector here")
    if (new_data.innerHTML === targetElement.innerHTML) {
        console.log("Same data")
    } else {
        console.log("There is some difference here")
    }
})
```

**parsedHtml** is the same HTML page but with updated data. I need to match the exact same node element (by using multiple selector like --> `.card .text-data`).

I could use an array of selectors and loop over it to query in the original DOM and the new one. But my question won't be answered :

> Can we retrieve the original query selector from a node element ?

Comment: What is `parsedHtml`? How does it relate to the document you're calling `querySelectorAll` on?

Comment: jQuery is out of the question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated my post. It's like the same HTML document but with updated data. For #Dalibor, yes pure JS

Comment: It's really not very clear what you want

Comment: @Liam I've added more context, maybe better ?

Comment: Make your forEach callback function take the _index_ of the current element as parameter as well, then you can use that same index to fish the corresponding element out of your other list.

Comment: I would make an array of selectors, and then iterate over that, and query the `document` and `parsedHtml`. Like so: 
`['.sel1' , 'sel2'].forEach(selector => {  const a =  document.querySelector(selector); const b = parsedHtml.querySelector(selector); doSomethingWith(a , b)}) `.  That way if your selector if well defined  not pointing to more than 1 element, you can be sure you are looking at the same element of each document.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we retrieve the original query selector from a node element ?

No, you can't. An element can be found using a wide variety of selectors. Nothing in the element you receive tells you what selector was used to find it.

> parsedHtml is the same HTML page but with updated data.

Assuming the **structure** is the same, you can relate them by index, see `***` comments for new/updated lines:

```
let selector = ".card .text-data, .section-1"; // ***
let targets = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // ***

let parser = new DOMParser();
let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(htmlData, 'text/html');

let parsedTargets = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // ***
targets.forEach(function(targetElement, index) {
// *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
    let new_data = parsedTargets[index]; // ***
    if (new_data.innerHTML === targetElement.innerHTML) {
        console.log("Same data")
    } else {
        console.log("There is some difference here")
    }
})
```

But if elements have moved around in these data updates, how you relate them will depend very much on what those changes are.

---

You've said:

> I would like to avoid relying on index

You haven't said why, but if you're making changes that would invalidate the index, then you're making changes to the tree that are likely to make it impossible to relate elements across trees (unless they all have unique IDs or something). Anything structural will require that the trees be structurally the same. Even if you built something that seemed to work in cases A, B, C, and D, it would likely break in case X that no one on the team thought to test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like to avoid relying on index. I could use an array of selector and then query two times. One in the original DOM, and another in the new one, but I would prefer to know if we can retrieve the original selector in a node element

Comment: @Baptiste - I've updated the beginning of the answer. The selector used to find the element is not stored anywhere; the element doesn't know how it was found.

Comment: @Baptiste - *"I would like to avoid relying on index"* Why not? Are you making changes that would invalidate the index? If so, you won't be able to build a selector based on an element in one tree to match an element in a tree that may not be the same as the first one.

Comment: Not for the moment but I'm always thinking about what could happen to make it more robust. If the first element is not present in the new DOM (no data for example), then the index solution won't work. But here, I'm more interested in the answer about my first question than how can I make it work

Comment: @Baptiste - An element with no contents is still in the DOM. I'm afraid we can't give you better suggestions without much more information. And structural changes are going to scupper just about anything you do.